# SEO Keyword Density Issue

Tags: seo

I have a website that has a keyword density of 8% and 4% for my keywords, but I only used the keyword once. The website doesn't have a lot of actual text. Does this high keyword density hurt my site's SEO even though I only used it once? I checked my keyword density using the SEO Review Tools density checker.

Comment: Will you be penalized for using a keyword one time? No, just try to use words naturally in a sentence and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response!